# Iteration in a list which contains a dictionary, a list and a tuple

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to solve a problem

```
l=[2,-8,9,0,-77,0,9.4,"hello","san",90,"a",(4,8,9),[8,9,9,"shree",{'a':1,'b':2,'c':[2,9,9,9.00]}]]
```

I need to create two lists and add in first list, if number is odd and in second list if number is even, either number in tuple or list inside list.
If string then ignore that. If there is dictionary then check there values is odd or even and add corresponding list as odd and even.

My code is this, but I am getting difficulty how to proceed further.

```
l=[2,-8,9,0,-77,0,9.4,"hello","san",90,"a",(4,8,9),[8,9,9,"shree",{'a':1,'b':2,'c':[2,9,9,9.00]}]]
even=[]
odd=[]

def fun(l):
    for i in l:
    if not isinstance(i,basestring):
        if i%2==0:
            even.append(i)
         else:     
            odd.append(i)

print even
print odd
print fun(l)
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be indentation at "if not isinstance(i,basestring):"

Comment: if possible, please post your expected output

Comment: @akashkarothiya    
Expected output is 
even=[2,-8,0,0,9.4,90,4,8,8,2,2]
odd=[9,-77,9,9,9,1,9,9,9]

Comment: @Zafi if there is any indentation problem i may solve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to call your `fun` function recursively if the current element is `list`, `tuple` or `dict`, thus iterating and adding *their* items.

```
even=[]
odd=[]
def fun(lst):
    for x in lst:
        if isinstance(x, (list, tuple)):
            fun(x) # recursively call for x
        if isinstance(x, dict):
            fun(x.values()) # call for values
        if isinstance(x, (int, float)):
            if x % 2 == 0:
                even.append(x)
            else:
                odd.append(x)

lst = [2,-8,9,0,-77,0,9.4,"hello","san",90,"a",(4,8,9),[8,9,9,"shree",{'a':1,'b':2,'c':[2,9,9,9.00]}]]
fun(lst)
print(even, odd)
# [2, -8, 0, 0, 90, 4, 8, 8, 2, 2] [9, -77, 9.4, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9.0, 1]
```

Comment: Sir Thank you very much, but 9.4 is even , isn't?

Comment: Would add even and odd as return values instead, even though his original code does not do it either.

Comment: 9.4%2 = 1.4000000000000004, which is not 0, so it's not even!

Comment: @user5956891 But it is not really odd, either. Even and odd are not well-defined (if at all) for decimal numbers. So you might as well filter those out, as well.

Comment: @tabias_k I got it as zafi described "9.4%2 = 1.4000000000000004, which is not 0, so it's not even!"

Thank you very much tobias_k Sir

Answer (score 1):

You need a series of if-else or switch to manage all different kind of possibilities.
If it's a *list* a *dict* a *number* so on..

Answer (score 1):

Consider this:

```
l=[2,-8,9,0,-77,0,9.4,"hello","san",90,"a",(4,8,9),[8,9,9,"shree",{'a':1,'b':2,'c':[2,9,9,9.00]}]]

def descend(o):
    if isinstance(o, (list, tuple)):
        for v in o:
            descend(v)
    elif isinstance(o, dict):
        descend(o.values())
    elif isinstance(o, (int, float)):
        print o
```

This prints:

```
>>> descend(l)
2
-8
9
0
-77
0
9.4
90
4
8
9
8
9
9
1
2
9
9
9.0
2
```

This can be turned into a generator:

```
def descend(o):
    if isinstance(o, (list, tuple)):
        for v in o:
            for r in descend(v):
                yield r
    elif isinstance(o, dict):
        for r in descend(o.values()):
            yield r
    elif isinstance(o, (int, float)):
        yield o
```

Which results in:

```
>>> list(descend(l))
[2, -8, 9, 0, -77, 0, 9.4, 90, 4, 8, 9, 8, 9, 9, 1, 2, 9, 9, 9.0, 2]
```

Then we can split the list:

```
even = []
odd = []

for x in descend(l):
    (even if x % 2 == 0 else odd).append(x)
```

Which results in:

```
>>> even
[2, -8, 0, 0, 90, 4, 8, 8, 2, 2]
>>> odd
[9, -77, 9.4, 9, 9, 9, 1, 9, 9, 9.0]
```

Comment: Tailor made for recursion :)

Comment: @Dan D. thank you very much .your solution is helpful  I got it but i think 9.4 is even, isn't?

Answer (score 0):

You can start with this:

```
[even.append(x) if x % 2 == 0 else odd.append(x) for x in l if isinstance(x, int)]
```

This will place even numbers to `even` and `odd` numbers to `odd`. For `tuples`, `lists` and `dicts` you will need (as stated by Marco) a sequence of if-else in a `for` loop.

Comment: thank you very much but how will i know that next entity in parent list is dictionary and list or tuple