# sorting different Data type in python

Tags: python-3.x

```
li=[22 , True , 22/7 , {"Staat":"Deutschland" , "Stadt" : "Berlin"}  , 69 
       , ["Python" , "C++" , "C#"] ,
       ("Kairo" , "Berlin" , "Amsterdam")  , False , "Apfel" , 55 ]
```

How can I sort this list in multiple lists , one list for each data type (int , str , dict, etc..)

```
for x in li:
        
        if type(x) == float:
            double = x
            print("double" ,double )
        elif type(x) == str:
            strings = x
            print("strings" ,strings)
```

```
it is too long ,  and its does not combine similar data in one list
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40931071/iteration-in-a-list-which-contains-a-dictionary-a-list-and-a-tuple may be this will give you some idea..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
li=[22 , True , 22/7 , {"Staat":"Deutschland" , "Stadt" : "Berlin"}  , 69 
       , ["Python" , "C++" , "C#"] ,
       ("Kairo" , "Berlin" , "Amsterdam")  , False , "Apfel" , 55 ]


# this function groups elements by type
def group(lists):
    groups = dict()
    for i in lists:
        a = str(type(i)).split(" ")
        typ = a[1][1:-2]
        if typ in groups.keys():
            groups[typ].append(i)
        else:
            groups[typ] = [i]
    return groups


print(group(li))
```

RESULT:

```
{'int': [22, 69, 55], 'bool': [True, False], 'float': [3.142857142857143], 'dict': [{'Staat': 'Deutschland', 'Stadt': 'Berlin'}], 'list': [['Python', 'C++', 'C#']], 'tuple': [('Kairo', 'Berlin', 'Amsterdam')], 'str': ['Apfel']}
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use a dictionary that has type(x) as keys:

```
lists_by_type={};
for x in li:
    print (x)
    if type(x) in lists_by_type.keys():
        lists_by_type[type(x)].append(x)
    else:
        lists_by_type[type(x)]=[x]
```

This gives you then a dictionary with lists for each data type

result would be something like:

```
{int: [22, 69, 55],
 bool: [True, False],
 float: [3.142857142857143],
 dict: [{'Staat': 'Deutschland', 'Stadt': 'Berlin'}],
 list: [['Python', 'C++', 'C#']],
 tuple: [('Kairo', 'Berlin', 'Amsterdam')],
 str: ['Apfel']}
```

Comment: I wanted to use dictionary , but this is an assignment for Uni , and they demand we use a List.